# Read Hyperlinks, changing data to bold and font size through apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am working on an automation project in which I am using Java with Apache POI to read the data from excel. However, my requirement is to read the hyperlink and it should remain as a hyperlink only as I am importing hyperlinks into a desktop application.

Plus I want other formatting should also get copied into that application.
FYI: Desktop application can do everything that an excel can do.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you already have a sheet object created out of a workbook object, the next step is to just read the hyperlinks using apache poi, the following snippet should do the job:

```
Cell cell = sheet.getRow(0).getCell(0);
Hyperlink link = cell.getHyperlink();
```

But again, does your cell contain multiple URLs or a single URL...?
Also, regarding the formatting can you elaborate your question a bit more with some example?

P.S: Everything you need is already well documented here: http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html

Comment: This is helpful, In this way we are able to read hyperlink data, but what I need is to create a same copy means it should remain a hyperlink only instead getting converted into a string.

Comment: Or if we have other means by which I can import hyperlinks and other formatting(Bold/Italic) of data done in excel to my application. PS: I am using Java.

Comment: If I have understood it right, you need to read some cells and create an exact replica somewhere else and along with preserving cell data & formatting,right? Then, you can iterate through your old data get the cell value (text/ date/ numerical etc.) use `newCellStyle.cloneStyleFrom(oldCell.getCellStyle());`  and apply this `newCellStyle` onto your newly created cells thus would apply formatting as in the original.